How to list all apps on a device registered to receive FCM push notifications?
Using a recent version of Android.  Solutions requiring root are okay.

Should be possible by scanning the AndroidManifest.xml of all installed apps. Firebase enabled apps should have a <service> entry with an action <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" /> as mentioned here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client#manifest

https://public.addonsdetector.com/detected-sdks. I'm not affiliated.
